# omniauth with omniauth-google-oauth2 or google-api-ruby-client?

Tags: omniauth, google-api-ruby-client

If a web application just needs to authenticate users with a google account with omniauth, in other words, users can just login with their google account.

What's the best choice to choose between the two gems:

omniauth-google-oauth2 or google-api-ruby-client ?

Answer (score 1):

omniauth-google-oauth2 is your best choice, because "omniauth" gem not dependent on suppliers and perfectly integrates with Devise